# How to get value within a week of a specified date on mysql

Tags: mysql, weekday

How to get value within a week of a specified date on mysql?

Example: date is 04-23-2010.

I want to query between start and end of 04-23-2010's week.

Comment: Example data and expected output please.

Comment: Post is now updated with example. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function.  For example, to filter results for all records where `col_date` is in the same week (Sunday-Saturday, inclusive) as 23rd April 2010:

```
WHERE DATE(col_date) BETWEEN
                           ADDDATE('2010-04-23', 1-DAYOFWEEK('2010-04-23'))
                       AND ADDDATE('2010-04-23', 7-DAYOFWEEK('2010-04-23'))
```